# getColor in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I know, getColor is deprecated and we can fix it by:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

but in Fragment I got information: Required Context found Context?

So how to avoid this ?

Answer (score 4):

Write the below code:

```
context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorWhite) }
```

Actually, you are passing `context` of type `Context?`. But you have to pass of type `Context`. For that you have to check that, `context` should not be null.

For that reason, `let` function is used. If `context` is not null then the code within let block will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the container `Activity`'s context into the `ContextCompat` method.

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.your_color);
```

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
set1.fillColor= ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.chart_fill)
```

i use `ContextCompat` and `requireActivity()` instead `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` for context can be `null` so you should do the following:

In your fragment

```
    private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
             this.context = context;
        }
```

to `getColor`

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getActivity().getResource().getColor(R.color.youColor)

Comment: this is deprecated